# Class with defaulted protected destructor not trivially-destructible but derived class is?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, destructor

In the following exemple the first static assertion fired but not the second:

```
#include<type_traits>
struct A{
 protected:
  ~A()=default;
};
struct B:A{
  //this static assertion fails
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<A>::value,"");
};
//this static assertion succeeds
static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<B>::value,"");
```

(checked with GCC,Clang,MSVC,ellcc)

I don't understand why A can not be trivially_destructible, inside B, while B is trivially destructible. This seems to be in contradiction with these 2 paragraphs of the C++ standard, where accessibility is not mentionned:

**[class.dtor]**

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> (6.1) — the destructor is not `virtual`,
>
> (6.2) — all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
>
> (6.3) — for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such
> class has a trivial destructor.

**[dcl.fct.def.default]**

> A function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted
> on its first declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, because from an outside point of view, `A` is *not destructible at all!* The destructor is `protected`, so if you have a `A* ptr`, calling `delete ptr` will fail to compile.

Comment: So `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value==false` does not imply that T is not *trivially-destructible* Ouch....

Comment: @Oliv It's defined as `std::is_destructible<T>::value && (destructor is trivial)`, and `is_destructible<T>` is defined as roughly `declval<T&>().
~T()` being a valid expression, independent of context. And that's just not the case if the destructor is protected.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Sebastian Redl answer: `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value==false` does not imply that the type is **not** *trivially-destructible*.

So if one use it in template programming, it is much better not to use standard library type traits, but to directly use compiler intrinsic. For exemple with gcc:

```
#include<type_traits>
struct A{
    protected:
    ~A(){};
};
struct B:A{
  //Bad: fails while the fact that A is trivially destructible
  //could be used to implement optimized function member in B.
  static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<A>::value,"");
  //Good: __has_trivial_destructor actualy return what is name says!!
  static_assert(__has_trivial_destructor(A),"");
};
```